# Swift struct external padding

Tags: swift, xcode, llvm

So I have the following struct in swift

```
typealias float = Float32
typealias Point = float2
typealias Int = UInt32

//This is a struct that is meant to be the elements in an array that is immensly acessable to c
//CAREFUL this is LIKELY mirrored in a different thing
public struct Info {
    var position:Point = Point(x: 0, y: 0)
    var strength:float = 1
    var altitude:float = 3.141592 / 2.0
    var azmuth:Point = Point(x: 0, y: 0)
    var state:Int = 0
}
```

This struct is stored inside of an array that is allocated with `Array(repeating: ...`

Every frame I pass a pointer into that array into my c++ code where I have a mirroring struct here

```
struct Info {
    float positionX;
    float positionY;
    float strength;
    float altitude;
    float azmuthX;
    float azmuthY;
    int state;
    float pad; //WHy???
};
```

Now notice the extra float "pad" it is in there because without it in the struct declaration when I go to read elements other than the first element the data was offset by the size of one float (things would be shifted one field over).

Why is the pad field on the c++ struct necessary? What is the extra float or reason for the extra padding in Swift?

Comment: `typealias Int = UInt32` is a bad idea because it shadows the built-in `Int` type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`float2` is the Swift mapping of the C type `simd_float2`, which is
defined in `<simd/vector_types.h` as

```
/*! @abstract A vector of two 32-bit floating-point numbers.
 *  @description In C++ and Metal, this type is also available as
 *  simd::float2. The alignment of this type is greater than the alignment
 *  of float; if you need to operate on data buffers that may not be
 *  suitably aligned, you should access them using simd_packed_float2
 *  instead.                                                                  */
typedef __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(2))) float simd_float2;
```

The key point is

> The alignment of this type is greater than the alignment of float

and you can verify that with

```
print(MemoryLayout<float>.alignment)  // 4
print(MemoryLayout<float2>.alignment) // 8
```

This causes the *alignment* of the Swift type `Info` to by 8, and its *stride* (i.e. the offset
in bytes between contiguous `Info` elements when stored in an array) to be 32.

```
print(MemoryLayout<Info>.alignment) // 8
print(MemoryLayout<Info>.stride)    // 32
```

On the other hand, the C type `struct Info` has only  `float` and `int`
members, which all have an alignment of 4 bytes. Without the
final `float pad;` member, the offset between contiguous elements of this type in an array is 28 bytes, not 32.

That explains the difference. What you actually should do is to define
the type in C only, and import that definition into Swift. This is
the only way which  is guaranteed to preserve the memory layout,
as Joe Groff from Apple writes at
[Mapping C semantics to Swift](https://forums.swift.org/t/mapping-c-semantics-to-swift/2688/2):

> If you depend on a specific layout, you should define the struct in C and import it into Swift for now.